# Sum of binomials gives indeterminate result... why?

Tags: special-functions, summation

I am defining a function that involves a sum of binomial coefficients:

```
a[r_, k_, mx_] = Sum[Binomial[r + 2*k - d, d], {d, k, mx}]
```

For some inputs, this works fine.  For others, it gives an indeterminate result.  For instance:

```
In[235]:= a[4, 1, 3]

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
```

There is no issue when computing the same sum but not as a function e.g.

```
In[232]:= Sum[Binomial[4 + 2*1 - d, d], {d, 1, 3}]
Out[232]= 12
```

Moreover, the sum in this case amounts to 5+6+1=12, so nothing strange is going on.

Any suggestions of what is going wrong and how to fix it?  I have a feeling it has something to do with the HypergoemtricPFQ function that is used to evaluate the `Binomial` expressions.  Thanks!

Comment: You should use `:=` when setting the function

Comment: "I have a feeling it has something to do with the `HypergeometricPFQ[]`" - yes, the result returned is only *generically correct*, and can fail for special inputs, which unfortunately are the ones you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetDelayed` to define your function:

```
In[24]:= a[r_, k_, mx_] := Sum[Binomial[r + 2*k - d, d], {d, k, mx}]

In[25]:= a[4, 1, 3]
(*Out[25]= 12*)
```